# how do sites like izuum.com find the cdninstagram query strings hashes

Tags: url, hash, instagram

How do sites like izuum.com and instadp.com generate hashes for cdn url for instagram profile pictures.
For example this is a valid url for getting a profile picture for a certain user.
https://scontent-vie1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/103998180_275128876942548_3059889593731211331_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-vie1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_ohc=lj3OsUw00j8AX-jAe8-&oh=16b5e14db9780318d116bf7fe99027eb&oe=5F194AE2

My question is how are the _nc_ht , nc_ohc and oh are calculated/generated

Comment: Just for reference, this is a full size image. I want to get cdn url for getting full size profile picture for userNames on instagram

Comment: Those websites scrape instagram data on server or use Instagram API to fetch data, then parse scraped data to frontend. CDN information is in API response or you can get them when you scrape data from Instagram by using a crawling tool

Comment: The public facing instagram website does not provide any data about 1080x1080 profile picture. So they are not using any crawling/scraping tool. I am not sure about Official Instagram API. Do you have any experience using the the official API? Does it give you the 1080x1080 picture url?